# Using content from the project in tests

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, mstest

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 and it's integrated testing functionality.
I have an XML file in my project which is set to copy to the output directory.  I can access the file just fine when I compile and run the project.  But it doesn't exist when I attempt to access it within a TestMethod.

It looks like the test is run with the working directory set to an "Out" directory created within the TestResults directory.  I can set a breakpoint before I use the file.  If I then copy the file into this "Out" directory and continue running the test it accesses the file properly.  But that is not really how I want my automated tests to function.

Is it possible to tell VS to copy the build directory into this working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found somewhat of a solution.  Though I'm not too happy with it.

Under the **Test**->**Edit Test Settings** I edit the current settings.
Under the **Deployment** tab, check the **Enable deployment** checkbox.  In the **Additional files and directories to deploy** add your bin\Debug directory (looks something like src\LocalModels.test\bin\Debug)

I suppose you could add each file you need and it would be a bit faster.  It all seems a bit ridiculous.